# ListView show ImageView OnClick on custom position outside ListView

Tags: android, xml, android-listview

I have a listview with custom items, and there are some items that have OnClickListener. What im trying to do is when i click on custom item show and ImageView below that item, BUT that Image is bigger than the cell of the listview so i need it to put outside of it and determine the X and Y and then show it just below the item of that cell. I tryed a lot lot of thing but im not getting the image in the correct place. Any ideas how can implement this?

Here is my last code that is approach of it, but im still not getting to work it well in all cases.

Note that this "tooltip" image is in the layout that contains the listview.

```
    tooltipImage.setX(mListView.getX()); 
    tooltipImage.setY(mListView.getY() - getTotalHeightofListView() / mListView.getChildCount());
    tooltipImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Here is the layout that contains the listview and the ImageView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/custom_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:scrollbars="none" />


   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/tootltip"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:scaleType="centerInside"
       android:src="@drawable/tootltip"
       android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So the ImageView is in the same container as the ListView?  Maybe you could post that layout xml.

Comment: @krislarson I added the layout so you can see it

Comment: try to get the childView(convertView) of listView  when you click. use this childView getX  as x  and getY+getHeight as y to locate your imageView, of cause, you should add up the listView x,y value.  this may help.

Comment: @davidleen29 Thanks i will try it, what do tou meen with: of cause, you should add up the listView x,y value. this may help ?

Comment: the  x, y value by the childView you calculated is just  relative to its parent(listView),not to the relativeLayout. so must add up the listView x,y to be relative to relativeLayout.( in your case ,not necessary)

Comment: Hi! i tried that but im not getting the image in the correct position, always is on top of the cell. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally to accomplish this i put the "tooltip" image in my Base Activity, and to position it on the screen i get the X and Y from the image clicked and position the tooltip there:

```
int[] listViewCoords = new int[2];
listView.getChildAt(pos).findViewById(R.id.image).getLocationOnScreen(listViewCoords);
getBaseActivity(listViewCoords[0] + imageWidht, [1] + imageHeight);
```

And on my baseActivity:

```
toolTip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
toolTip.setX(x);
toolTip.setY(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're call it a "tool tip" so it sounds like you want it to "float" on top of the item.  But what happens when the user scrolls?

Here's a suggestion:  You can use an ExpandableListView to achieve something like this.  Your list item would be the first level.  When you click on the list item, it would expand to show your ImageView just beneath it.  That way, when the user scrolls the ImageView will move with it.

I have done something like this where I even hid the expand/collapse indicator so that the ListView did not appear to be an ExpandableListView.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but i need to put this outside the listview, like you say "floating" below the custom item for just 2 seconds, so i wont have the problem when the users scrolls.